# iOS silent notifications for killed apps after device restart

Tags: ios, notifications, push

According to the documentation silent notifications are processed by the delegate *[application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)* also when the app is in "Not Running" state. This behavior does not apply if the app was force-quitted by the user.
But the documentation mentions that if the device has been restarted after a force-quit, the notification will trigger again the app launch on the device.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):

> ... However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app ***or restart the device*** before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Can anyone confirm this to be working (maybe with earlier iOS versions)?

My experience (using iOS 10.x) is that if the app was force-quitted the app won't be restarted even after (multiple) device reboot.

Comment: If user has force killed your app, then your app won't receive silent notifications.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation mentions the exceptional case with restarting the device and _without_ starting the killed app again.

Comment: Yes it is in the documentation but I tried it and if you killed the app, even after a restart you don't get notifications.